# Setting InfoWindow Postion in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am drawing a set of Polygons on to Google Maps and would like to have an InfoWindow pop up at the center of each when I click on it.

```
function attach_info_window(polygon, centroid, title){
    var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: title,
      position: { lat: centroid[0], lng: centroid[1] }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function() {
      info_window.open(map, this);
    });
  }
```

The problem is, the window shows up in the NW corner every time. The 'position' parameter seems to be ignored completely. I also tried setting the position on click with

```
event.latLng
```

But that returns undefined, even though the API docs specify it, so that doesn't work either. Curiously, it works just fine if I use a Marker instead of the Polygons.

Comment: What is that centroid?  Is it just an array with [0] and [1] ?  But the real problem is probably: " position: ..." requires a Google Maps point.  Try this: position: new google.maps.LatLng(centroid[0], centroid[1])

Comment: Why do you not pass a marker instead of this as second param with info_window.open(map, this) -> info_window.open(map, new new google.maps.Marker({...}) . Setting the position of marker with help of centroid and LatLng-Object. In this example is open-method of infowindow used as well: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple?hl=de

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the second argument in open()

```
info_window.open(map)
```

works great. I was passing "this" in order to bind it to that specific polygon among many. I still don't understand why this works, and neither

```
info_window.open(map, poly)
```

nor

```
info_window.open(map, this)
```

works

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
info_window.open(map, this);
```

Will not work for anything but a google.maps.Marker.  The second argument of [InfoWindow.open](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) can only be a google.maps.Marker, a Polygon or Polyline won't work there.

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)
"In the core API, the only anchor is the Marker class. However, an anchor can be any MVCObject that exposes a LatLng position property"